# Spring authentication - getting the logged in name

Tags: spring, security

I have been able to authenticate a user and can get their logged in username to show on their page. But instead of the username I would like to use the name of the user.

The assembler for this:

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails buildUserFromUser(UserEntity userEntity) {

        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();
        //String name = userEntity.getName();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = enabled;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = enabled;
        boolean accountNonLocked = enabled;

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role : userEntity.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        User user = new 
        User(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

        return user;
    }
}
```

The UserDetails that I'm using restricts to the set constructor so I can't get the name through it. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the `User` class and make a user that has the additional information you want and return that from the `buildUserFromUser` method.  Something like this:

```
public class CustomUser extends User {
    private String name;

    public CustomUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String name) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Instantiate this user in your `buildUserFromUser` method passing in the name from the `userEntity` object:

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails buildUserFromUser(UserEntity userEntity) {

    String username = userEntity.getUsername();
    String password = userEntity.getPassword();
    String name = userEntity.getName();
    boolean enabled = userEntity.getActive();
    boolean accountNonExpired = enabled;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = enabled;
    boolean accountNonLocked = enabled;

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for(Role role : userEntity.getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    return new CustomUser(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, name);
}
```

Then you can get the custom user from the Spring security context like this:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = ((CustomUser)authentication.getPrincipal()).getName();
```